# This field expects a java.lang.String but the script returned a java.lang.Class

Tags: string, groovy

```
public class MyClass {

    public static main(String[] args) {

        def field = "Passed";

        def passTime = use(TimeCategory) {
            new Date() + 60.days
        }

        if (field.equals("Passed")) {
            String newPassTime = passTime.format('M/d/yy')
            return newPassTime
        }

    }
}
```

I would like the output to be a string but for some reason the script is returning a class.

How can I return a string from this code?

Comment: What is returning `java.lang.Class`. I don't see any return methods?

Comment: It is groovy and sorry I forgot to add the return of the variable

Comment: You're returning from a static void main method? I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test does not support your output. I tried

```
    if (field.equals("Passed")) {
        String newPassTime = passTime.format('M/d/yy')
        System.out.println(newPassTime)
        System.out.println(newPassTime.getClass())
        return newPassTime
    }
```

and it gives following output

```
C:\Users\athakur\Desktop\TempDump>groovy test.groovy
Apr 19, 2015 10:04:36 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-nio] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
6/18/15
class java.lang.String
```

So it should return a String a and not `java.lang.Class`.